# Asp Net Core 3.1 Large Data Export Excel with ClosedXML

Tags: excel, asp.net-core, export, closedxml

I need to get 400-500k data in excel output, but in the Worksheet.SaveAs (stream) part, the data takes up 6gb of ram at a time and the application closes when the ram is not enough on the computer. What I want is to get excel output, but even if it cannot do this, I want to at least prevent the application from closing. What should I do for this?

sample excel data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdLi5.png)

this is the sample code (I can't show it because some parts are private)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXURO.png)

error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smTSy.png)

This application will run on the server and its current features are 12gb ram 4 core cpu,
at least how much do you think we should increase these features?

Comment: you can try to use paging, try to load 100 row in one request and append the data in file

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible, I have to show 600k data on a single page.

Comment: Which version of ClosedXML version are you using? From [this link](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues/86), it seems that [ClosedXML 0.93.0-beta2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/0.93.0-beta2) has been released and should address this issue, try to use this version.

Comment: i use 0.95 version, should I replace it with the version you said?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, you can have a try. Besides, since this issue is related to ClosedXML, I think you could also post this question on the [ClosedXML github forum](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/issues).